# WinForm crashing when accessing resources

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing a WinForm application and I have some embedded resources (the graphic layout of the form). The problem is that when I start the application on my machine it runs perfectly, but if I pass it on another pc it may or may not work. On the last computer I tried (Windows 7 64bit, .NET 4.0 installed) it blocked when I tried to access resources. Here is the code which blocks the app, and below there is the full exception thrown.

```
//Note: notifierName is a string passed as an argument
_icon = new NotifyIcon
{
    Text = notifierName,
    Icon = SystemIcons.Application,//Properties.Resources.Tray,
    Visible = true
};
try
{
    _icon.Icon = Properties.Resources.Tray;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.WriteLog(e.ToString());
}
```

After tracking down what was causing the exception, I tried to set all resources to "embedded resources", the .exe was doubled in size (so the images were actually saved in there) but the same error occurred. I think I'm missing something about how resources work, because passing the same exe on another machine isn't causing all these troubles. Thanks for your help.

> System.TypeLoadException: Unable to load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' dall'assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>      in System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethod(RuntimeModule module, Int32 methodToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount)
>      in System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandleInternalCore(RuntimeModule module, Int32 methodToken, IntPtr[] typeInstantiationContext, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr[] methodInstantiationContext, Int32 methodInstCount)
>      in System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 methodToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
>      in System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData..ctor(RuntimeModule scope, CustomAttributeRecord caRecord)
>      in System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tkTarget)
>      in System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributesInternal(RuntimeAssembly target)
>      in System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetNeutralResourcesLanguage(Assembly a, UltimateResourceFallbackLocation& fallbackLocation)
>      in System.Resources.ResourceManager.CommonSatelliteAssemblyInit()
>      in System.Resources.ResourceManager..ctor(String baseName, Assembly assembly)
>      in PatcherNET4.Properties.Resources.get_ResourceManager()
>      in PatcherNET4.CustomControls.Notifier.Create(String notifierName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs about when you compile an application with `.Net 4.5` but run on  `4.0.`In  .Net 4.5 `ExtensionAttribute` removed from `System.Core` and add `mscorlib`.

[Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as)

[Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933643/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as)

Comment: Great suggestion, surely you're right. Now, how can I change the target platform to .NET 4.0 from solution properties in VS?

Comment: I think change target but you can test both.

Comment: It is already set to .NET 4.0, but now I think the problem could be in a referenced DLL. I'm going to check it out

Comment: It's yet crashing. The only dll I am referencing is protobuf-net (from Marc Gravell) and I am 100% sure I am passing the .NET 4.0 version.

Comment: There is an excellent breakdown of this issue posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as/13750130#13750130