# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions' from assembly mscorlib

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm getting this error whenever I'm initializing an instance of Entities class. But this perfectly runs on my local PC. The full exception is as follows.

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TypeExtensions.GetStaticProperty(Type type, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(Type providerType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(String providerTypeName, String providerInvariantName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__2(ProviderElement e)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DbProviderServices()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterDbProviderServices()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 t)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at testEF.Data.ERP_Model.ERP_entities..ctor() in c:\Users\Dilshan Jayaweera\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\testEF\testEF\Data\ERP_Model\ERP_entities.cs:line 10
   at testEF.Form1.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Dilshan Jayaweera\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\testEF\testEF\Form1.cs:line 23
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did my own research and found out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933643/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as#19933787). According to this I'm guessing the class `RuntimeReflectionExtensions` is also moved from System.Core to mscorlib in .NET 4.5 and since I had also targeted to .NET 4.5, I changed it back to .NET 4.0, guess what? it solved the problem!

Comment: @c0d3b34n pointed this out much before you posted this answer. If not mark his/her answer as accepted answer, at least give them some credit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using libraries which were created with .net higher than 4.0? Check your Target Framework and be sure that you use only classes from that version.